# Mocha --file with mochaHooks works on CLI but not as file property in .mocharch.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, es6-modules

In `package.json` the following script works perfectly for running my mocha tests without any issues. This includes specifying my implementation of a global `beforeAll` hook via  `-file src/tests/mochaHooks.mjs`

```json
"scripts" {
  "test": "mocha --file src/tests/mochaHooks.mjs --loader=ts-node/esm src/tests/**/*.test.ts"
}
```

This is all well and good. However, when I tried switching to a `.mocharc.json` configuration file I get an error reported for the `mochaHooks.mjs` file that worked fine previously.

This is the `.mocharc.json` file:

```json
{
  "extension": ["js","cjs","mjs","ts"],
  "package": "./package.json",
  "file": ["src/tests/mochaHooks.mjs"],
  "loader": "ts-node/esm"
}
```

This is my `mochaHooks.mjs` file contents:

```js
exports.mochaHooks = {
  beforeAll(done) {
    // initialization code here
    done()
  }
}
```

This is the runtime error from mocha:

```
ReferenceError: exports is not defined in ES module scope
    at file:///Users/markericson/Develop/sowrulesengine/src/tests/mochaHooks.mjs:1:1
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:194:25)
```